# MySQL Clustering and replication

Tags: mysql, replication, cluster

I want to setup a MySQL cluster setup of two servers (M1-M2). I also want to setup MySQL replication between two servers (M1-M3).

Is it possible to setup both clustering and replication as above. Is it a good idea to have a setup like this ?

I want to have server M1 and M2 in the amazon cloud and other server M3 in our datacenter.

Comment: Hi Santhosh can share how you did this Mysql Clustering any document/how to or blog

Comment: Do you want to configure NDB tables and another engine's tables in the same DB or when you say cluster are you referring to replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite possible.  MySQL cluster uses the `NDB` (Network Database) engine to "replicate" changes between the two nodes.  So it does not use the binary logs at all.  You can therefore setup the other server `M3` to do straight binary log replication.

You could theoretically use whatever engine you wanted for `M3`, but beware that certain DML and most DDL will fail for certain engines (or at least behave differently).  So the most robust would be to have `M3` be a single node `NDB` instance.  But you could set it up to use `MyISAM` or `InnoDB`, just realize that it could lead to issues down the road...

As for if it is a good idea, that depends.  As long as the `M1` -> `M3` replication is a Master-Slave relationship (with `M3` being the slave), I don't see the harm in that...

Answer (score -2):

I've never done mySQL replication or clustering, so this post is just a "for what it's worth" post.  If I were setting this up, and have clustering AND replication, then I would made the "cluster" master-master replicate and then the second "cluster" would be the slaves setup as master-master.  So basically cluster CL1 has 2 mySQL servers, setup using master-master replication (so they both have the same data).  Then for cluster #2, CL2, I'd setup as the "slave" servers that get replicated from CL1, but again, they would be setup as master-master replication so that all of THOSE in THAT cluster all have the same data, since it is a cluster.

However, this might not be how mySQL replication and clustering works.  Hopefully I don't get a downvote, since I'm just giving you my 2 cents about how I would do it.  Again, I've never done this and I've thought about it, but no needed to, and most of our companies databases are Oracle.

Comment: Actually, after further research, maybe you shouldn't do replication AND clustering; again not sure, since I don't know what the "correct" thing to do here.  However, there's a good writeup on mySQL clustering - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-cluster-for-two-servers.html